# How do I clone only a subdirectory of a Git repo?

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to clone only a subdirectory of a Git repository [using this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository) but it doesn't work.

I use Ubuntu for Windows (WSL) and I used these commands:

```
$ git init
$ git remote add -f origin <repo-ssh>
$ git config core.sparseCheckout true
$ echo 'FolderName/' >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
$ git pull origin master
fatal: couldn't find remote ref master

$ git pull origin main
 * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

> `'FolderName/'` in this case: `'Exercise2/'`

I don't know how to fix.

And the remote branch name is `main`.

Comment: What does "`'FolderName/'` in this case: `'Exercise2/'`" mean? What do you need to "fix"? Please read [ask].

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a bit ambiguous.
But I think this should solve your problem:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/your/repository
```

Follow the rest steps as usual. Just change your remote origin url.